# Не понимаю, почему не работает проверка на число

Tags: javascript

По идеи, программа должна проверять два числа на то что они числа (по отдельности), а потом сравнить их. Но всё зацикливается, почему?

```js
const firstNumber = prompt("Введите первое число: ");
while (isNumber(firstNumber) === 0) {
    const firstNumber = prompt("Введите первое число: ");
}
const secondNumber = prompt("Введите второе число: ");
while (isNumber(firstNumber) === false) {
    const secondNumber = prompt("Введите второе число: ");
}


if (firstNumber > secondNumber) {
    alert("Первое число больше второго");
};
if (firstNumber < secondNumber) {
    alert("Второе число больше первогоо");
};
if (firstNumber == secondNumber) {
    alert("Числа равны");
}

function isNumber(n) {
    return isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: замени const на var :)

Comment: Грех копипастия вижу в коде твоём.

Comment: @Эникейщик, не всё что видишь, всегда есть истина

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас тут сразу несколько проблем.

1. Не повторяйте `const` или `let` внутри блока, так вы создаёте новую переменную с видимостью только внутри блока, а не переопределяете прежнюю.
2. Используйте let, если будете переопределять переменную.
3. Поскольку функция `isNumber(n)` возвращает логическое значение, строгое сравнение его с нулём всегда будет ложным.
4. Две части сравнения в `isNumber(n)` противоречат друг другу.
5. Второй раз вы опять проверяете первое число.

```
let firstNumber = prompt("Введите первое число: ");
while (!isNumber(firstNumber)) {
    firstNumber = prompt("Введите первое число: ");
}
let secondNumber = prompt("Введите второе число: ");
while (!isNumber(secondNumber)) {
    secondNumber = prompt("Введите второе число: ");
}

firstNumber = Number(firstNumber);
secondNumber = Number(secondNumber);

if (firstNumber > secondNumber) {
    alert("Первое число больше второго");
};
if (firstNumber < secondNumber) {
    alert("Второе число больше первогоо");
};
if (firstNumber == secondNumber) {
    alert("Числа равны");
}

function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, долго не мог понять в чем проблема))

Comment: добавь приведение строки к числу, иначе сравнение может дать неожиданные результаты

Comment: Добавил. Так-то, наверное, нужно как-то объединить проверки и приведение, но тогда уже получится совсем неузнаваемый фрагмент)

Answer (score 0):

Уберите с вашего кода бесконечные циклы, тогда не будет зацикливаться

```js
const checkNumbers = () => {
  const one = prompt("Введите первое число: ");
  const two = prompt("Введите второе число: ");

  if ( one > two )
    alert('1 > 2')
  else if ( one < two )
    alert('1 < 2')
  else if ( one == two ) alert('1==2')

   //мы получили результат сравнения первой пары чисел, проведем еще одну проверку
    checkNumbers()
}

checkNumbers()


function isNumber(n) {
    return isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: да это конечно помогло бы, но тогда как будет работать проверка на число?

Comment: чувак, ты просто убрал циклы! спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотите бесконечно долго вызывать проверку на число?

Comment: isNumber нигде не используется

Comment: Осознал. Приношу свои извинения. Я не разобрался в задаче. И начал нести бред. Готов ловить камни